# How to generate XML file from elements map?

Tags: java, xml, recursion

I need to generate an XML file from just having a map, which contains the parent element and his children.

Map looks like this:

```
Map<String, List<Element>> elementMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Element>>();

root: el1 el2 el3 el4 // root is the parent and el1... are his children.
el1: el5 el6
el2: el7 el8
```

Expected ***XML Model***:

```
<root>
  <el1>
    <el5></el5>
    <el6></el6>
  </el1>
  <el2>
    <el7></el7>
    <el8></el87>
  </el2>
  <el3></el3>
  <el4></el4>
</root>
```

***Can you give me some tips, algorithms how I could generate that XML?***
I thought about recursion, but I don't know where to start.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough information for anybody to help.  You need to show a sample of the actual XML you want to produce, as well as the definition of `Element` and how it maps to XML.

Comment: Work from top to bottom? Just iterate over each entry and their value. iterate the value and call same function to check if they have even more children.

Comment: And you don't want to set any elements value like `<el1>123</el1>`?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I've updated my post, Element is: org.w3c.dom.Element
No, I don't need values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts were good.
You have to use iterating every one of your map keys and generate the list of elements based on values from this key. The result should be append to the general document.

You haven't posted your `Element` class. I will show some example based on `Map<String, List<String>> elementMap`.

Here is code snippet:

```
import com.epam.lab.model.exceptions.CreateDocumentConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class XmlBuilder {

    private DocumentBuilder builder;

    private Document doc;

    /**
     * Constructs an item list builder.
     *
     * @throws CreateDocumentConfigurationException
     */
    public XmlBuilder() throws CreateDocumentConfigurationException {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new CreateDocumentConfigurationException("exception create new document", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a DOM document for an array list of items.
     *
     * @param elementMap map of items.
     * @return a DOM document describing the items.
     */
    public Document build(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
        doc = builder.newDocument();
        doc.appendChild(createItems(elementMap));
        return doc;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a DOM element for an array list of items.
     *
     * @param elementMap the map of items
     * @return a DOM element describing the items
     */
    private Element createItems(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
        Element e = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> anItem : elementMap.entrySet()) {
            e = doc.createElement(anItem.getKey());
            for (Node node : createItemsList(anItem.getValue())) {
                e.appendChild(node);
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

    private List<Node> createItemsList(List<String> items) {
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String item : items) {
            Element item1 = createItem(item);
            result.add(item1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a DOM element for an item.
     *
     * @param anItem the item
     * @return a DOM element describing the item
     */
    private Element createItem(String anItem) {
        // if you need some text element to your element - just append it here.
        return doc.createElement(anItem);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the text content for document
     *
     * @param name element
     * @param text content
     * @return text element
     */
    private Element createTextElement(String name, String text) {
        Text t = doc.createTextNode(text);
        Element e = doc.createElement(name);
        e.appendChild(t);
        return e;
    }


    private String generateXmlContent(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
        String content;

        Document doc = build(elementMap);
        DOMImplementation impl = doc.getImplementation();
        DOMImplementationLS implLS = (DOMImplementationLS) impl.getFeature("LS", "3.0");

        LSSerializer ser = implLS.createLSSerializer();
        ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);
        content = ser.writeToString(doc);

        return content;
    }

    public void writeToXmlFile(String xmlContent) {
        File theDir = new File("./output");
        if (!theDir.exists())
            theDir.mkdir();

        String fileName = "./output/" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_"
                + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".xml";

        try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))) {
            try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_16)) {
                out.write(xmlContent);
                out.write("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Cannot write to file!" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws CreateDocumentConfigurationException {
        XmlBuilder xmlBuilder = new XmlBuilder();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = MapFactory.mapOf(MapFactory.entry("root", Arrays.asList("element1", "element2", "element3")));

        String xmlContent = xmlBuilder.generateXmlContent(map);
        xmlBuilder.writeToXmlFile(xmlContent);
    }
}
```

After generating ***XML document*** you have to write it to file.
But you have to ***prepare XML content*** before writing, something like:

```
private String generateXmlContent(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
    String content;

    Document doc = build(elementMap);
    DOMImplementation impl = doc.getImplementation();
    DOMImplementationLS implLS = (DOMImplementationLS) impl.getFeature("LS", "3.0");

    LSSerializer ser = implLS.createLSSerializer();
    ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);
    content = ser.writeToString(doc);

    return content;
}
```

And finally ***writing to file*** can look like:

```
public void writeToXmlFile(String xmlContent) {
    File theDir = new File("./output");
    if (!theDir.exists())
        theDir.mkdir();

    String fileName = "./output/" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_"
            + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".xml";

    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))) {
        try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_16)) {
            out.write(xmlContent);
            out.write("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot write to file!", ex);
    }
}
```

Utility factory for creating Map, based on literals:

```
public class MapFactory {    
    // Creates a map from a list of entries
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOf(Map.Entry<K, V>... entries) {
        LinkedHashMap<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
    // Creates a map entry
    public static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> entry(K key, V value) {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
    }
}
```

After executing `main()` I have got following XML file `XmlBuilder_1456910256665.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
    <element1/>
    <element2/>
    <element3/>
</root>
```

Comment: He put in a comment that it is of type `org.w3c.dom.Element`. Which is a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Neijwiert It is `JDK` core library. You don't need any 3rd party libs for this code.

Comment: Ah didn't know, haven't used it.

Comment: @Neijwiert Now you know. And can use it for your purpose.

Comment: @nazar_art, it is possible to make it work for more generic Map which can have nested values of Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>>???

Comment: @SandeepKumar If to make the long story short. Yes, it is possible. You have to build your elements from the last `Map<String,List<String>>` and assign it to general `Map<String, ...>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use below fuction for converting the Map to an XML string.

```
public static String maptoXML(Object hashMap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XMLEncoder xmlEncoder = new XMLEncoder(bos);
    xmlEncoder.writeObject(hashMap);
    xmlEncoder.close();
    return bos.toString();
}
```

Ref:http://pritomkumar.blogspot.in/2014/05/convert-map-hashmap-or-listarraylist-to.html?m=1

Comment: I don't think `org.w3c.dom.Element` is Serializable.